# How to disable PrettyPhoto media plugin on small screen

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to know how to disable the PrettyPhoto on small screen layouts, I am doing a project and client have that requirement, he does not want to display pop up gallery for small screen so kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when you small screen layouts, you mean mobile devices. Your problem can be solved by checking the User Agent first, and then only initialising prettyPhoto if your User Agent doesn't match any of the User Agent related to Mobile devices.

Only initialise it if the user agent is of a desktop browser or a iPad if you wish to include that.